# How to give an Activity an OnDragListener

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a simple program that allows the user to drag an ImageView object around on the screen. There are two other stationary ImageView objects on the screen that causes a TextView to display a message indicating which of the two ImageView objects the user dragged the drag-able one to.

Currently the user can only drop the image at one of the two ImageView objects on the corners, and I want the user to be able to drop the image anywhere on the screen.

I am having trouble setting up an OnDragListener for the background area of the activity.

Thanks in advance

Comment: v = ((ViewGroup)findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);

Found out the code above returns the View object to v. From there I said v.setOnDragListener(DropListener); and everything works as intended

Answer (score 0):

[OnDragListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnDragListener.html) is a View event, it cannot be triggered from an activity.

All you need to do is the add the Listener to your View, and call back the activity when an event occurs. What is the Panel you use for your background?

Comment: I found the solution. It's in the comment to my question